# How to calculate the sum $\textrm{C}_{n}^{1}-\textrm{C}_{n}^{3}+\textrm{C}_{n}^{5}-....$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation, combinations

I know I can calculate it by the following method:
$1-i=\sqrt2(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}) \Rightarrow (1-i)^n=\sqrt2^n(\cos\frac{n\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{n\pi}{4})$
at the same time, $(1-i)^n=\textrm{C}_{n}^{0}+\textrm{C}_{n}^{1}(-i)+\textrm{C}_{n}^{2}(-i)^2+\textrm{C}_{n}^{3}(-i)^3+...+\textrm{C}_{n}^{n}(-i)^n$

and you equal the real and the imaginary part and you get that $\textrm{C}_{n}^{1}-\textrm{C}_{n}^{3}+\textrm{C}_{n}^{5}-....=\sqrt2^n\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}$.
But I was thinking, is the any other method to solve this sum?

Comment: Probably hundreds of ways. Since you have a proof using the binomial theorem, then you can break it down into a proof by induction.

Comment: @Hellen I know you can do it by induction after you know the result. But what if you do not know that it needs to be equal with that?

Comment: The same. You don't need to know the result. Don't get misled by the square root and the sine. They are only simpler expressions depending on the parity of $n$ in disguise.

Comment: Summation by parts, taking derivative of the binomial coefficients and sum of the $(-1)^n$, should also work.

Comment: As a typesetting/notation suggestion, the notation $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ is *much* more common than $C^r_n$.  There are a number of problems with the notation $C^r_n$, in particular that the notation $C^n_r$ is also in use to mean the same thing.  Of course, match whatever notation is used by your professor, but once out of the class I'd recommend switching to what is much more standard.

Comment: There are other methods, and this one is the best.

Comment: Thanks for all the support. @Did said this method is the best but the point of the question was to find out if there is another method if it does not come in my mind to use complex numbers to solve this.